# White film at top of bottle

Tags: contamination, bottle

After 7 days in bottle I find out a white film at the top of the beer. This film isn't in every bottle, just in 1/3 of batch.

I openned one and it's tasted good.

I need to know if it's an infection or a normal issue of bottle's fermentation.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bze0KzJYRKm5aUd0ZFJwYUFFRFNuWHpFd0lWSk5kOWxLTDBv

Comment: Wow, that's pretty pretty nasty already after only 7 days!  Not normal!  Review your sanitation procedures!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like pellicle from some organism.   Probably a wild yeast or a souring bacteria. It shouldn't be harmful, but can sure ruin a beer.

You got a lot of headspace there and oxygen for things to grow. I would seperate the infected ones and secure for bottle bombs if you plan on keeping them.